# What is a load current?

Tags: voltage, dc, load

I was trying to calculate the voltage drop of a copper wire due to its length, 
given that it has a fixed size and it transmits DC current.
Anyway when trying to calculate it with one of this [online-calculators](http://www.calculator.net/voltage-drop-calculator.html?material=copper&wiresize=0.4066&voltage=120&phase=dc&noofconductor=1&distance=50&distanceunit=kilometers&amperes=1&x=69&y=24),
it asks me about a load current.  The voltage drop seems to vary dramatically in relation to this paramenter but I still haven't completely understood its menaning.
I know what an electrical load is : an electrical component that consumes electric power", but I couldn't find a detailed explanation for what a load current is.

Comment: It's the current the load consumes.

Answer (score 1):

*Load current* in this context is simply the current thru the wire.

As you say, a *load* consumes power.  That power is delivered electrically, which means it is the product of voltage and current.  The load current is just that current.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Anyway I didn't really get what you mean by "the current thorugh the wire". Is this the current at the beginning, or at the end of the wire? Isn't current decreasing through the wire? I mean, voltage drops with distance but resistance remains the same, so shouldn't current decrease? Am I wrong? :)

Comment: @Gab: You need to go back and learn the fundamentals.  Your questions are *very basic*.  I don't really know how to explain it more simply.  And no, the current does not change along the length of the wire.  The voltage can, though.

Comment: Thank you, You're right I made confusion, current stay the same

Comment: Still I have a doubt, hope you have time for a quick answer. Why should I insert the current in the calcualtor?  I inserted voltage and resistance ( material of the wire, size and length). Shouldn't current be derived from them( Ohm's law) ?